# Why does implicitly[ClassTag[T]] resolve successfully?

Tags: scala, implicit

In the following simplest example I have no compile errors:

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    test[Int]()
  }
  def test[T <: Int : ClassTag]() = println(implicitly[ClassTag[T]])
}
```

the program prints `Int`. But I don't understand why an object of type `ClassTag[T]` can be found for `implicitly[ClassTag[T]]` invocation? the only thing I did was to provide generic type argument. Where does the `ClassTag[Int]` come from?

Comment: Short answer, it's defined in the ClassTag companion object. You can also find other definitions for primitive types such as Boolean or Char.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:` symbol defines a *context bound*, which means that the compiler has to have an instance of `ClassTag[T]` in its implicit scope. It's syntactic sugar for the following:

```
def test[T <: Int]()(implicit $ev: ClassTag[T]) = println(implicitly[ClassTag[T]])
```

The call to `implicitly` will then take `$ev` as the required instance.

But this of course pushes the question a little bit further: where does the `$ev` (evidence) come from? To quote [the Scala documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html#using-a-context-bound-of-a-type-parameter) (referring to `TypeTag`, but the same applies to `ClassTag`):

> Given context bound [T: TypeTag], the compiler will simply generate an
>   implicit parameter of type TypeTag[T] and will rewrite the method to
>   look like the example with the implicit parameter in the previous
>   section.